# How to stretch all navigation elements in navigation bar using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a navigation bar using flexbox. I want to make all elements in flexbox stretch equally in the available space horizontally.

Expected navigation bar is this:

[image]

but my navigation bar is this:

[image]

I think you understood the problem my navigation bar is leaving too much space in the left and right sides. I want to use whole space by stretching all navigation links.

my html code is:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel=stylesheet href=ej42.css>
    </head>

    <body>
            <div><ul>
                    <a href=# >HOme</a>
                    <a href=#> about me</a>
                    <a href=#>about you</a>
                    <a href=#> about foo</a>
            </div></ul>
    </body>
 </html>
```

my css code is:

```
a{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:monospace;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    border-right: 2px solid #555;
}
ul{
    padding:2px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    background-color:#555;
}
a:link{
    background-color:#afa;
    color:white;
}
a:visited{
    color:black;
}
a:hover{
    background-color:#8d8;
}
a:active{
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    ul{padding:0;}
    padding:7px;
}
```

I tried to use "stretch" value for justify-content property but that didn't work and all links aligned to left. I am unable to make the navigation bar as I expected. It will be very helpful if you solve my problem

Comment: FYI @user9218974, the `flex` tag refers to Apache Flex, not the CSS flexbox model.  I went ahead and removed the tag -- `flexbox` is the one you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `flexbox`. This will automatically fill up the spaces and adjust dynamically to new navigation elements.

```css
a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 2px solid #555;
}

ul {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #555;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}

a:link {
  color: white;
}

a:visited {
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #8d8;
}

a:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 7px;
}

li {
  width: inherit;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel=stylesheet href=ej42.css>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div><ul>
      <li><a href=# >Home</a></li>
      <li><a href=# >About me</a></li>
      <li><a href=# >About you</a></li>
      <li><a href=# >About foo</a></li>
    </div></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but how did the li element stretch equally its width is set to inherit

Comment: It inherits the width from its parent, which is `100%`. You could achieve the same thing by doing `width: 100%`

Comment: but if the width is 100% why did it not took the whole space in the container

Comment: Because the `ul` is using `flexbox`, therefore the `flexbox` assigns all available spaces to its children equally.

Answer (score 1):

The only way i think is to put this style into "a"

```
a{
  display: block;
   width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Attention to the following errors:
- Closing the div before the ul
- ul in style is in the middle of the style of a: active